# How can i stop intercept touch event?

Tags: android

I made ImageView inside Gallery.

When users are touch phone with one finger, i want to send touch event to gallery, and if users are touch phone with two finger, i want to send touch event to ImageView.

So, When user make one finger touch event, i intercept touch event by return true in onInterceptTouchEvent at Gallery.

But, when i want to send touch event to ImageView, there's no method to send touch event.

I try to call ImageView's onTouchEvent in Gallery's onTouchEvent method, but it failed.

And i also try return false by calling onInterceptTouchEvent manually, and it also failed.

How can i stop intercept touch event and give touch event to ImageView again?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to diable all touch:(override)

```
 public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev){
 return true;
 }
```

Comment: I mean, i intercept touch event using return true at Gallery. But, which i meant to do is stop intercept touch event. And i want to make  ImageView get touch event again.